# Graphic in Latex document

Tags: graphics

[image]i would like to have a function in my document. It shall be f(x)=0 für 0<=x<2.5 and g(x)=1 for 2.5<=x<5 and i might put another h(x)=2. I tried to plot it with the \addplot command but i dont like the looking with the quadratic system of coordinates. Is their any extern program to create something and put it into texmaker?

Edit: i tried this here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=4]
\addplot[thick] {{0}};
\addplot[thick] {{1}};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The first thing is that the graphic is above the text i put before i dont know why. Then i dont want it to be so quadratic and not closed on the upper and right side. And i dont even know how to really put the conditions in there so function g(x) starts where f(x) ends and so on. 
I dont know if all of this is possible in there :/.
Thanks

Comment: Sure, but if you use an external program, it is off-topic here. You can customize the visual appearance of `pgfplots`' plots. What have you tried, what would have to be different?

Comment: I ad it to my problem.

Comment: the plot will have moved as you put it inside a `figure` that is the _only_ reason to use `figure`:  to take the content out of the document flow so it can be re-inserted at a different place to help with page breaking.

Comment: now you should be able to compile it. Okay i could remove figure then, what about the other things?

Answer (score 1):

like this (it is not very clear, how you like to have present your function)?

[image]
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
             xmin=0, xmax=10,
             ymin=0, ymax=4,
             no marks]
\addplot [very thick, blue, domain=0:2.5]  {0};
\addplot [very thick, blue, domain=2.5:6]  {1};
\addplot [very thick, blue, domain=6:6.5]  {2};
\addplot [very thick, blue, domain=6.5:10] {3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this is almost perfect. Is it possible to have the coordinate system broader? I think it looks better in my document. Can i remove the upper line of the coordinate system as well as the right one to have a usual open system of coordinates?

Comment: all this is possible. to be clear, what you like to have,  please provide an sketch of desired function.

Comment: I add a pictue of how the function should look like. I can edit the values myself its more about the general look of the system.

Comment: @chri11, see edited answer